# Scanning Memory in 64 bit?

Tags: c#, memory, 64-bit

A while ago I created a memory scanner in C# that would read through a processes' memory and look for certain values (for example the locations of every occurrence of the integer 42). Since then, I have revisited this project, and am trying to design it to work in a 64 bit system. The problem I'm running into is that 64 bit processes are granted up to 8TB of virtual memory (compared to a humble 2-4GB on 32 bit systems)! For my code at least, it is impossible to scan every address of the range 0-8TB in any reasonable amount of time.

I tried starting my scans at the Process.MainModule.BaseAddress but I don't know where to stop reading and I'm definitely missing important values. How do I narrow down the field so I can scan the range of what the process is actually using?

Comment: You need to get a memory map of the process. Do a search for "process memory map" and that should get you started.

Comment: I did search for process memory map and similar terms but all I could find were explanations of how paging and virtual memory work. It was useful information but didn't really pinpoint how to achieve the creation or how to view a memory map of an external process. However, this did lead me to examine other methods of exploring a processes virtual memory.

Comment: Scanning through the address space calling `VirtualQueryEx` is how to build a process memory map.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring out what sections of memory, or virtual pages, were being used by using the VirtualQueryEx library method. I used this function to create my own "memory map" and identify the used and accessible pages. Pinvoke has a nice example on how to do this here: [PInvoke Article](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.virtualqueryex)

By looking at the sections of virtual memory that were flagged as MEM_COMMIT and checking to be sure the permissions didn't include PAGE_GUARD I was able to find the necessary chunks of memory that were relevant and readable.

Comment: Could you add some sample code, then accept your own answer? :)